# JButton not working

Tags: java, linux, swing, jbutton, jfilechooser

I recently developed a GUI for my application , that runs shell scripts on Linux Ubuntu 10.04. It was working fine until today. I designed a button so that , clicking the button would open a prompt for selecting a file. The JFileChooser is used in the actions. But from today morning, without any error, clicking on the button does not do anything. It is not simply working all of a sudden. What is this error?
Can somebody please help? Is this any error related to the OS/Java installed?

Thanks in advance.

```
int yorn = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
String user = System.getProperty("user.home");
File file = new File(user+"/.afile");
if (file.exists()){
    yorn = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"There seem to have a Previous project , Do you want to back up??");

    if (yorn == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){ // yesoption clicked!

        //choose folder to open!
        JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
        jf.setDialogTitle("Back up location?");
        String pathname = null;
        jf.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        jf.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = jf.getSelectedFile();
        pathname = f.getAbsolutePath();
        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,pathname);
        try{
            Process copy = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh "+user+"/myprojects/.backup.sh "+pathname);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
        }

        //open file for analysing..
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Backing up complete.. ");

        JFileChooser jf2 = new JFileChooser();
        jf2.setDialogTitle("Open the Codebase");
        String pathname2 = null;
        jf2.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        jf2.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f2 = jf2.getSelectedFile();
        pathname2 = f2.getAbsolutePath();
        String username = System.getProperty("user.home");
        File writefile = new File(username+"/.afile");              

        Writer output = null;
        try {
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(writefile));
            output.write(pathname2);
            output.close();

            //    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,username);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } else if (yorn == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){       

        JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
        jf.setDialogTitle("Open the Codebase");
        String pathname = null;
        jf.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        jf.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = jf.getSelectedFile();          
        pathname = f.getAbsolutePath();
        String username = System.getProperty("user.home");
        File writefile = new File(username+"/.afile");              
        Writer output = null;
        try {
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(writefile));
            output.write(pathname);
            output.close();

            //    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,username);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code.. What is does, is that , it check if afile exist and if it does, prompt for a backup. If the back up is an yes, then do back up and open a new window for another selection , and if back up is a no , then the file selection is opened. As i mentioned, this was working till the time I asked the question. It stopped working all of a sudden. Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: Could you create a small example that doesn't work on your system? Doesn't this work: `new JFileChooser(".").showOpenDialog(null);`?

Comment: Like dacwe said, you should probably provide an example. Also, have you tried running your script on another machine? If it's really some error with your JVM or OS configuration then taking the same JAR (or class files) and running them on another machine should work.

Comment: All JFileChoosers are broken since Curiosity landed this morning. Nasty side-effect.

Comment: you should provide your java detail as well(open jdk or sun jdk)

Comment: @dacwe: Thanks that small example did work.... but not my work.. I ll provide the code as an edit.

Comment: java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.10.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: and the funny fact is, it is still working on my Virtual machine, inside this OS.

Answer (score 2):

You should as asked before provide an example but here is a piece of code that works for me, tested under linux/MAC OS/Windows:

```
/* chooser is of type JFileChooser of course */
chooser.setDialogTitle("title of your dialog");
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY /* change it to fit your needs */);
chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Comment: Thanks @nathan for the effort, but I had it working.. I dont think it is not about the code, it is something else.

Comment: Maybe you should expose what was your error and how you solved that. It might people in same situation.

Comment: I have added the code, I ll surely share the solution if I find :). Thanks